# gradle build with subprojects, git feature branches and jenkins multibranch pipeline: how to only run tests on affected subprojects

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, multibranch-pipeline

Say we have a Java project with subprojects like

- persistence
- businessA
- businessB
- web

where everything depends on `persistence` and `web` depends on both `business` subprojects.

We use git and feature branches.

We use jenkins with pipelines and jenkins' multibranch feature to build and test those feature branches every time there is a push to the central repo.

The problem is that the codebase is rather large and running tests needs 1+ hour overall. It would be great if the the pipeline would only execute tests of the subprojects that changed (and its dependents) in respect to `develop` branch. Gradle can do incremental builds but when jenkins creates a workspace for a feature branch gradle needs to do a full build. (e.g. a new feature branch changes code in `web` subproject only and there is no need to run all tests on the other 3 subprojects)

**So how do we avoid a full build (especially running all tests) on a new feature branch in a Jenkins multibranch pipeline?**

Answer (score 0):

I now use gradle remote cache because that it is what I want.

I just needed to write a small tool to remove old cache entries.